# Selecting a cell with VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select a cell in excel with vba.  I want to be able to use to variables(i & e) to choose a cell.  Where **i = 3** and **e = 13** I would like to be able to

```
ActiveCell(e, i).Activate
```

and it select cell C13.

```
ActiveCell(e, i).Activate
```

does work but only when original active cell is A1.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A simple search here of "vba excel select cell" should turn up literally dozens of answers to this question. Please at least try to find a solution yourself before posting a question here, as chances are quite good someone has asked before and gotten an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Look into the R1C1 syntax if you want to refer to columns by their index.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308

Comment: Thanks Emmad! Exactly what I was looking for.  Ken - I did search and found simmilar info but not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is because `ActiveCell` literally returns a `Range` object that represents the active cell in the active window. So `ActiveCell(e,i)` is basically equal to `ActiveCell.Offset(e-1,i-1)`. If your orginal active cell is not A1, of course your code will refer to the wrong cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put comments in the code so it should be really easy to understand.

Run the below code first

```
Sub Main()

    Dim i As Long ' row variable
    Dim e As Long ' column variable

    i = 3 ' row 3
    e = 13 ' column 13 ("M")

    ' this will put: Cells(3,13) in Range "M3"
    Cells(i, e) = "Cells(" & i & ", " & e & ")"


    ' if you want to offset the current active cell then
    ' use Offset(x, y)

    '  use negative x to offset up
    Cells(i, e).Offset(-1, 0) = "1 up"

    '  use positive x to offset down
    Cells(i, e).Offset(1, 0) = "1 down"

    '  use negative y to offset left
    Cells(i, e).Offset(0, -1) = "1 left"

    '  use positive y to offset right
    Cells(i, e).Offset(0, 1) = "1 right"


    ' same principles apply when using range object
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Cells(i, e)

    r.Offset(-2, 0) = "2 up"
    r.Offset(2, 0) = "2 down"
    r.Offset(0, -2) = "2 left"
    r.Offset(0, 2) = "2 right"

    Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

then look at your sheet and analyse what command does what :)

[image]